# Passing a parameter into a parameter

Tags: batch-file, parameters

Help!!

So I have a batch file that looks at the name of a file and then prints to sumatrapdf.exe to a printer name based on the original file name.
The printer name is stored in a parameter.
When I echo the printer name parameter it is correct.
When I pass the printer name parameter to the print program, it errors, assuming its because it cannot see the printer name parameter.  (thinking I somehow need to pass across another set of "%"'s so that batch file knows its a parameter.

```
FOR %%F IN (%C:\Users\nick\Desktop\Test1%\Shelf*.csv) DO (
 set filename=%%~nF
 Set filename1=%%F
 goto tests
)
:tests
echo "%filename1%"
echo "%filename%"

Set "Shelf-01Printer=NPIBBF846 (HP Color LaserJet CP2025dn)"
Set "Shelf-07Printer=NPIBBF846 (HP Color LaserJet CP2025dn)"
Set "Shelf-97Printer=NPIBBF846 (HP Color LaserJet CP2025dn)"
Set "Hook-09Printer=HP LaserJet P2050 Series PCL6"
Set "PrinterName=%filename%Printer"
Echo %PrinterName%

Start SumatraPDF.exe -print-to %PrinterName% "C:\Users\nick\Desktop\Test1\% filename%".pdf
Timeout /t 15
```

Comment: I suggest you to use the _standard array notation_ enclosing the _index_ or _subscript_ in square braquets: `Set "Printer[Shelf-01]=NPIBBF846 (HP Color LaserJet CP2025dn)"` or `Set "Printer[Shelf-07]=NPIBBF846 (HP Color LaserJet CP2025dn)"`, etc. You may process _array elements_ via `Delayed Expansion` this way: `Set "PrinterName=!Printer[%filename%]!"`. See [Arrays, linked lists and other data structures in cmd.exe (batch) script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990).

Comment: @Aacini, you are correct. This probably should be marked as a duplicate question.  Or I should have the delayed expansion example in my answer as well.  Just felt using the CALL was easier to explain then delayed expansion. It always seems to confuse new users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a space in your variable expansion: `% filename%`. Remove the space. But that doesn't fix your logic. Essentially you are trying to do double variable expansion. You can accomplish this using a neat trick with the CALL command.

```
CALL Set "PrinterName=%%%filename%Printer%%"
```

Using the CALL command gives you two phases of variable expansion.  When the CALL command executes the line of code becomes:

```
CALL Set "PrinterName=%Shelf-01Printer%"
```

Then the `SET` command executes and sets the variable to the appropriate printer name.